# Converting an arbitrary pulse to logic level

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, signal-processing, pulse

### Background:

I'm trying to measure the time interval between (4) different pulses with a baseline of ~2V and rougly 1.6V p-p . Currently I'm using the ADC on an STM32 to sample the four channels.

However, since I'm using the ADC its slow and the resolution of the time differences suffers.

### Problem:

I want to convert each pulse to a logic level, like in picture 1, so I can poll them using IO pins instead of the slow ADC.
[image: What I want]
I've messed around with an op amp differentiator in Multisim but I can't quite realize what I want. Is an differentiator the way to go or are there some other solution. Remember, I'm really only interested in the start of the different pulses.

TL;DR Converting an arbitrary sine-ish pulse to a logic level, how do I?

**Edit:**
My differentiator design I've been messing with, it doesn't quite work for some reason.

[image: Differentiator]

Comment: A differentiator is a good start, you'll also want to read up on peak detectors. And perhaps precision rectifiers.

Comment: The ADC of STM32 ain't slow, it's very high speed. But where do you see those time intervals, and what those time intervals are?

Comment: I don't see any pulses.  In figure 2.  I see a noisy waveform.  You want to know when the wave form gets noisy like that?  Maybe you could.  1.) AC couple, 2.) rectify, 3.) define some trigger level and use a comparator to output when the signal is above that level.

Comment: Well, the ADC is too slow for my purposes. I've added my not quite-working differentiator design, maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting "something changing" is really easy and, generating a pulse is also easy (based on that detection) but, the hard thing (that is undefined in your question) is the *criteria* for resetting the pulse: -

[image]

As per the graph I kidnapped and defaced, what is it about the signal (red) that **prevents** the detection pulse (green) resetting at the three points shown by the blue arrows in the picture?

How can you be so certain that as soon as the red trace dies down you can reset the pulse (as you have in your example)?

Why don't you just get into excel and do some fuzzy analogue / digital logical things on a set of samples and see how it shapes up. Excel is really great for stuff like this.

Comment: Well, at some point it should be resetable, when dV/dt goes below some value for some t (t is assumed to be larger than the width of the peaks).

Comment: You have to decide what aspect of your signal causes the pulse to reset. Also you say in your edit "it doesn't quite work" but that is unhelpful to those not blessed with telepathy.

Answer (score 0):

So your requirement is pretty much like "output `1` when the input is changing, `0` otherwise". Mathematically speaking: 
$$f(x(t)) = \begin{cases} 1 &\frac{dx}{dt}\neq0 \\0 &\frac{dx}{dt}= 0
 \end{cases}$$

So you need some kind of differentiator - either analog (opamp based) + comparator. Or digital - sample and compare two consecutive samples. Perhaps you will need to tune the sensitivity of it and add some hysteresis.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I've added a schematic of the differentiator design I've been working on, seems like the way to go but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working design of a sine-pulse to logic level converter, capable of converting frequencies from >10KHz to 3.3V. Sadly a dual-supply as of now, the reason for choosing the AD8047 is that it is very fast resulting in a nice fast rising flank.

[image]